# SOA (ish) architecture, where to place common code?

Tags: java, maven, architecture, soa, dependency-management

we have a soa-ish architecture which looks like this

```
frontend            ->domain A ->db 
frontend->business A->domain B ->db
frontend            ->domain C ->db
frontend            ->domain A ->db 
frontend->business B->domain B ->db
frontend            ->domain C ->db

other app A
other app B
```

we also have other applications which are not part of this soa stack.

from time to time we have the following discussion/problem:

*"i have code in domain A that is also useful in domain B but not in business services - where should i put the stuff with its tests".*

let's assume the code is very abstract and domain agnostic, something very generic that could also be used by the "other" applications outside of soa.

so the question is:

a) put it in a "generic-domain-stuff" module which all domain inherit via maven dependencies. This will probably end up growing and growing until it is a mess….

b) create a module "generic-stuff" which can be used by soa and the "other" applications. This will probably lead to a lot of small maven modules….

c) duplicate the code until you have three use cases, then refactor to a) or b). This screems DRY (don't repeat yourself)

i have people with 10+ years of "enterprise" experience around me but we never seem to find a proper solution/answer to the always same problems :)

i would be interested in hearing you experiences

Answer (score 2):

(b) should be the way to go. If the code/logic is so generic then it is best fit for a library. Application(s) needing this logic should use the library through maven (or any other dependency management mechanism). You should not allow one library to become a "god library". Break the library into smaller cohesive pieces as time passes. That way you can prevent it from growing too big and becoming a mess. Don't worry about many maven libraries - many small and cohesive libraries are better than one big monolithic "do it all" library.

Comment: Agreed -- this is the way to go. You should also check out the book, Implementing Domain Driven Design, by Vaughn Vernon: http://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577